# Can we join two table's column values of different databases in a single stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have two different databases Banking and Initial. Under banking, I have a table Customers and under Initial database, I have a table Funding. I wanted to join the value of the table "Banking.BankingID" with the value Funding.FundingId on a single stored procedure. How can we achieve that? I am really stuck here. Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can you will need to use the full path to the tables.

```
INNER JOIN [Banking].[dbo].[Customers] on [Banking].[dbo].[Customers].[BankingID] = [Initial].[dbo].[Banking].[BankingID]
```

This should work as long as the SQL user account has permissions to both databases, if the databases are on different servers you will need to look into `linked servers`

Answer (score 0):

Just `JOIN` them as usual, prefixing the database name:

```
SELECT *
FROM Banking.dbo.Customers C
INNER JOIN Initial.dbo.Funding F
ON C.BankingID = F.FundingId
```

Use the proper schema for your tables (I used `dbo` on my answer).